# 'Repeat' in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

I'm very new to Haskell, and I have a simple question.

What function can I use with a and b that will result in a, b times.

Example:
`a = 4 | b = 3`
Would return:
`[4, 4, 4]`

Thanks!

Comment: Hoogle as always is your friend: state the function you'd like to find: `Integral b => a -> b -> [a]`, and it will tell you the answer: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Integral+b+%3D%3E+a+-%3E+b+-%3E+[a]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`replicate`:

```
replicate 3 4
```

will be:

```
[4,4,4]
```

---

When you know what's the type of the function you need (in this case it was quite obvious that the function you needed had a type similar to `Int -> a -> [a]`) you can use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int+-%3E+a+-%3E+%5Ba%5D) in order to find it.

Comment: To get the *exact* behavior Peter described use: `flip replicate 4 3`

Answer (score 7):

You could also use recursion (although the solutions above should be preferred of course):

```
rep a 0 = []
rep a b = a : rep a (b-1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Of course peoro is right, you should use `replicate`.

However, a very common pattern for such tasks is to construct an infinite list, and take as much as you need from it (either using `take` or `takeWhile`):

```
rep a b = take b $ repeat a
```

Another (more educational than practical) approach is to use a list of the right length, and map all elements to a:

```
rep a b = map (const a) [1..b]
```

An very inefficient, but interesting version is

```
rep a b = until ((b==).length) (a:) []
```

Answer (score 3):

.. or simply something like that

```
> take 3 [4,4..]
> [4,4,4]
```